# How can I center the form at the top of this website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

can anyone help me center the email sign-up form at the top of this website:

https://new.dariningelsnd.com/

I'm pretty sure a little bit of simple CSS can do this but I can't figure out what class or whatever to edit here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the ID assigned to the parent form element in case the assigned class is assigned to other elements.

CSS:

```
#form_id {
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form_id">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: I tried doing this using the form ID which is "inf_form_647e604918a3f0a0c52cd6b907f9d7d3" but it didn't work. I tried using !important too and that still didn't work. I just don't understand what the problem is here. Something else somehow seems to be forcing it left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

On the `col-lg-0 middle` class, add `height: 33px;` and `display: block;` or `display: table-caption;`

[image]

Comment: Tried both those options but it still is showing up left aligned. I tried adding !important too but that also didn't work.

It's like something else somewhere is forcing it to be left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

In your div with class `row-menu-inner` you have 2 divs in it, The last div `<div class="col-lg-12 menu-horizontal"></div>` needs to be removed and it will adjust your form to the center since your are using flex.